# Invariance of Domain and Inverse Function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have been thinking about both of them for a while and in this case, let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n.$

In inverse function Theorem, since $Df$ is nonsingular, so is $Df^{-1}.$ Hence this gives $f$ an open map for free.

Now I think this is an example where "smoothness" is easier than "continuity".

Invariance domain is more or less the same. Except I guess we don't have the matrix condition so we don't immediately get $f$ being an open map for free. For example $f: U \to f(U)$ is bijective, now let $V$ be open in $f(U).$ Is the point of the (Brouwer) proof that its isn't obvious $f^{-1}$ continuous? That is for every open set $V \subset f(U)$, it isn't obvious that $(f^{-1})^{-1}V \subset U$ is open?